# VS SP1 messes up MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, visual-studio-2010

I installed VS SP1 and intellisense for Razor (MVC3) stopped working. Did numerous searches for a solution and found lots of references to Resharper which I don't use. So I reinstalled MVC3 which didn't fix the problem. I uninstalled MVC 3 then reinstalled and now my project won't load! So I reinstalled MVC twice and still it won't load!

Now all I get is "The project type is not supported by this installation."

Even though I keep successfully installing MVC3, it no longer appears in Add/Remove programs.

If anyone could give me some tips as to what I do next they would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Strange, is a complete reinstall of Visual Studio out of the question? Annoying bugs like this can often be solved a lot quicker by simply reinstalling the software.

I use 2010 and have encountered no problems with Razor or intellisense.

Comment: I too have had no problems until now! I've just done a repair install of Visual Studio and tried to reinstall MVC3. The standalone installer comes up with a "fatal error" and the web installer says it installed successfully but my project still won't open, MVC3 isn't listed as installed and there is no MVC3 project template. I am now uninstalling Visual Studio so I can start from scratch.

Comment: From memory I had an issue installing MVC3 to start with, I think it was a problem with the installer hanging. I did do a complete reinstall and that helped.